# Broadcast receiver for nought and Oreo + devices not working

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo, android-7.0-nougat

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private boolean screenOff;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF))    {
            screenOff = true;
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            screenOff = false;
        }

    }


   <receiver
             android:name=".ScreenReceiver"
             android:enabled="true"
             android:exported="true">
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.DREAMING_STARTED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DREAMING_STOPPED" />
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS" />
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                 <action android:name="android." />
             </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

> Not getting any callback on naught and oreo devices,tried on marshmallow devices its working fine .but on oreo devices its not working and also for battery connected and network change receiver not working .

Comment: Starting from Nougat, background optimizations have been made. Apps that target Android 8.0 or higher can no longer register broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts in their manifest.

Comment: I know about the behaviour changes ,but  I need it to get all the action callbacks . is there anyway to do this .

Comment: after searching i find this one is correct approach for this https://github.com/devggaurav/BroadcastReceiver-For-Naught-and-Oreo-devices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not register broadcast receiver in manifest.xml from Oreo.
You can see 
[Android 8.0 Behavior Changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes)

> Apps cannot use their manifests to register for most implicit
>   broadcasts (that is, broadcasts that are not targeted specifically at
>   the app).

**Solution**

Register your receiver in your related Activity instead. Like this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    BroadcastReceiver receiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction("android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED");
        receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // todo
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (receiver != null)
            unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }
}
```

You can add action as string same as manifest, if you don't find relevant constant string.

Comment: I know but what's the alternative ??

Comment: It will be activity specific ?

Comment: Where do you want to register it? You can register `BroadcastReceiver` anywhere context is available, like Services, Fragments and Dialogs etc.

Comment: https://github.com/devggaurav/BroadcastReceiver-For-Naught-and-Oreo-devices.
this is how someone has achieved this.

Comment: Excellent solution !, you should post this solution on others questions related to this.

Comment: You should post this library link as answer here. Many guys will have this problem too.