# Ways to registering broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

in the project that I got to work on there's a use of `Broadcast receivers`. Now, those receivers are registered in the `Manifest` and also there's this method:

```
private static void enableComponent(Context context, Class<?> component) {

    ComponentName connectionReceiverComponent = new ComponentName(context, component);
    context.getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(connectionReceiverComponent, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

I'm a bit confused about it, because since `Android 8` we can't register receivers in the `Manifest` anymore, instead we have to use runtime registration, using `context.registerReceiver()`, thus it is not necessary even to put the receivers in the Manifest. And yet, the registration that uses `ComponentName` still works on `Android 8` and `Android 9`.
Can you please explain what's difference between those two methods, and why it works and `Android 8` and beyond?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51221680/broadcast-receiver-not-working-in-android-oreo
check it bro

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html

Answer (score 0):

In Activity you can register like this.

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

  IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
  filter.addAction("SOME_ACTION"); 

  receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      //do something based on the intent's action
    }
  };
     registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}
```

Or in your ActivityManifest

```
<receiver
 android:name=".ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver">
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```