# BATTERY_CHANGED broadcast receiver not woking

Tags: java, android

I am working on an Android Studio project that does some actions when the phone is connects to a power source. In order to do this, I made a broadcast receiver that listens for `android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED` and launches a java activity. But it turns out my activity is never launched. Here is my code :

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "45441141645", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //This toast here is never displayed



        boolean charging = false;
        Toast.makeText(context, "Tried", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
        boolean batteryCharge = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING;

        int chargePlug = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
        boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
        boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;

        if (batteryCharge) charging=true;
        if (usbCharge) charging=true;
        if (acCharge) charging=true;

        if (charging) Toast.makeText(context, "Battery Charging", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;


    }


}
```

And a part of my manifest :

```
<receiver android:name=".Receiver"  android:exported="true" android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>
    </application>
```

I also tried to put some Log.d in my code to see where the problem was coming from but I didn't figure out anything

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: how are you registering the receiver?

Comment: @ArkaPravaBasu well in the manifest.xml file. And I also import the android.content.BroadcastReceiver class in my java file

Comment: you cannot receive this broadcast from static receiver since android 8.

Comment: @Pawel oh then how am I supposed to code this ?

Comment: You have to run a foreground service that displays a notification and register receiver there. Read more about it on similar questions like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51221680/broadcast-receiver-not-working-in-android-oreo

Comment: @Pawel oh thanks it worked !