# Not allowed to start service Intent - Android Oreo

Tags: java, android, android-8.0-oreo

I am currently using the startWakefulService function which is crashing in Oreo. I realise I either have to switch to startForegroundService() and use a foreground service, or switch to JobIntentService but based on my code below I am not sure what to do. (Sorry I am an android novice). Any points in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // Explicitly specify that GCMIntentService will handle the intent.
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GCMIntentService.class.getName());
    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));

    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
}
```

This is the current error I get when run on Android 8.x

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
>   Unable to start receiver com.heyjude.heyjudeapp.gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x1000010 pkg=com.app.app cmp=com.app.app/.gcm.GCMIntentService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{f602fba u0a114 RCVR idle procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I experience the same behaviour.

**Why this issue happens?**

> Due to the new [Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#services) of Android 8 and you should
>   not start services background.

**How I fixed it**

Migrate your `GCMIntetService` to `JobIntentService` instead of `IntentService`.

Please follow this steps:
1) Add the BIND_JOB_SERVICE permission to your service:

```
<service android:name=".service.GCMIntentService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"/>
```

2) In your `GCMIntentService`, instead extending the `IntentService`, use `android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService` and override onHandleWork
then remove the `override` in you `onHandleIntent`.

```
public class GCMIntentService extends JobIntentService {

    // Service unique ID
    static final int SERVICE_JOB_ID = 50;

    // Enqueuing work in to this service.
    public static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent work) {
        enqueueWork(context, GCMIntentService.class, SERVICE_JOB_ID, work);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {
        onHandleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        //Handling of notification goes here
    }
}
```

Then finally, in your `GCMBroadcastReceiver`, enqueue your `GCMIntentService`.

```
public class GCMBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GCMIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        // startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));

        //setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);

        GCMIntentService.enqueueWork(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    }
}
```

This implementation work for me after we update our target sdk to 27 and I hope it works for you.

Comment: WakefulBroadcastReceiver is deprecated?

Comment: @DylanBurton it's no longer useful when you support Android Oreo due to background check restrictions.

Comment: How would this be accomplished with Alarm manager (trying to schedule an alarm)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver):

> As of Android O, background check restrictions make this class no
>   longer generally useful. (It is generally not safe to start a service
>   from the receipt of a broadcast, because you don't have any guarantees
>   that your app is in the foreground at this point and thus allowed to
>   do so.) **Instead, developers should use android.app.job.JobScheduler to
>   schedule a job, and this does not require that the app hold a wake
>   lock while doing so** (the system will take care of holding a wake lock
>   for the job).

Only alternative is to start a ForeGroundService or use JobScheduler/JobIntentService

**You can start foreground service as follows:**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // Explicitly specify that GCMIntentService will handle the intent.
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GCMIntentService.class.getName());
    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context,intent.setComponent(comp));
    ...
}
```

You also need to call `startService()` from your Service class and display notification. You can follow my answer on this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51241184/background-service-is-not-working-in-oreo/51241791#51241791) for implementation details.