# How to run a service/daemon in Android TV Oreo at all times?

Tags: service, background-process, daemon, android-8.0-oreo, android-tv

I want to build an application for the Android TV platform. Part of this app is a service/daemon, which must start when the device boots, and must always run when the Android TV is powered on, even in stand-by.

Why do I want this service/daemon to run at all times? Part of my project is an application for portable devices (such as a smartphones and/or tablets), which will send commands via TCP to the Android TV app. Based on the kind of TCP message, the app will perform an action (power device on/off, push my app to the foreground etc.).

I have tried different code examples, but Android TV Oreo just kills this service after a while. I think these code examples were made before the Android Oreo restrictions.

An application like Kodi for the Android TV, has a web service that is always running in the background. Even on Oreo. but I can't figure it out how they have done that. Does anyone have some tips for me?

Edit: Yatse Remote Starter does what I want for Kodi, what I want to do with my app. It starts on boot, runs even in stand-by. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tv.yatse.android.remotestarter&hl=en. Still I would like to know how, so I can do it myself as well. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many android apps and services are running simultaneously. To lower the chance of problems which cause poor user experience, Android 8.0 apps has [two ways to limit what an app can do](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background):

> **Background Service Limitations**: While an app is idle, there are limits
>   to its use of background services. *This does not apply to **foreground***
>   ***services***, which are more noticeable to the user.
>
> **Broadcast Limitations**: With limited exceptions, apps cannot use their
>   manifest to register for implicit broadcasts. They can still register
>   for these broadcasts at runtime, and they can use the manifest to
>   register for explicit broadcasts targeted specifically at their app.

Therefore, you need to create a ForegroundService in order to continue processing of your app. You can check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51241184/background-service-is-not-working-in-oreo) regarding this issue.